# add d3 legends in a div with auto scroll

Tags: jquery, d3.js, legend

I want to add legends in a div so that it gets auto scroll when number of scatter plots increases. following is my sample code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en"> 
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">

        .axis path,
        .axis line {
            fill: none;
            stroke: black;
            shape-rendering: crispEdges;
        }

        .axis text {
            font-family: sans-serif;
            font-size: 11px;
        }

        .y1 {
            fill: white;
            stroke: orange;
            stroke-width: 1.5px;
        }

        .y2 {
            fill: white;
            stroke: red;
            stroke-width: 1.5px;
        }

        .y3 {
            fill: white;
            stroke: steelblue;
            stroke-width: 1.5px;
        }

        .line {
          fill: none;
          stroke-width: 1.5px;
        }

        div.tooltip {
            position: absolute;
            text-align: center;
            width: 50px;
            height: 10px;
            padding: 5px;
            font: 10px sans-serif;
            background: whiteSmoke;
            border: solid 1px #aaa;
            pointer-events: none;
            box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px #888;
        }

        .legend1 {
            width:45px;
            height: 5px;
            padding: 0px;
            overflow: auto;
            font: 10px sans-serif;
            background: yellow;
            border: 1px solid #bbb;
            background-color: #cccccc;
            box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px #888;
        }

        .title {
            font: 13px sans-serif;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

//Width and height
var w = 500;
var h = 500; // chart height
var padding = 50;

var now = d3.time.hour.utc(new Date);

var dataset = [
    [ 
        {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -5), y: 0}, 
        {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -4), y: 0}, 
        {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -3), y: 2}, 
        {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -2), y: 0}, 
        {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -1), y: 0}, 
        {x: now, y: 0}
    ],
    [
        {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -5), y: 3}, 
        {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -4), y: 1}, 
        {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -3), y: 3}, 
        {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -2), y: 1}, 
        {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -1), y: 5}, 
        {x: now, y: 1}
    ],
    [
     {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -5), y: 3}, 
     {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -4), y: 5}, 
     {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -3), y: 2}, 
     {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -2), y: 1}, 
     {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -1), y: 7}, 
     {x: now, y: 1}
  ],
     [
      {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -5), y: 5}, 
      {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -4), y: 2}, 
      {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -3), y: 3}, 
      {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -2), y: 4}, 
      {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -1), y: 6}, 
      {x: now, y: 1}
  ],
  [
   {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -5), y: 1}, 
   {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -4), y: 2}, 
   {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -3), y: 3}, 
   {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -2), y: 4}, 
   {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -1), y: 5}, 
   {x: now, y: 1}
    ],
    [
     {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -5), y: 5}, 
     {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -4), y: 4}, 
     {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -3), y: 3}, 
     {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -2), y: 2}, 
     {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -1), y: 1}, 
     {x: now, y: 1}
    ],
    [
     {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -5), y: 0}, 
     {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -4), y: 2}, 
     {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -3), y: 4}, 
     {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -2), y: 6}, 
     {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -1), y: 8}, 
     {x: now, y: 1}
    ],
    [
     {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -5), y: 8}, 
     {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -4), y: 9}, 
     {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -3), y: 7}, 
     {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -2), y: 6}, 
     {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -1), y: 5}, 
     {x: now, y: 1}
    ],
    [
     {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -5), y: 3}, 
     {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -4), y: 2}, 
     {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -3), y: 1}, 
     {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -2), y: 0}, 
     {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -1), y: 5}, 
     {x: now, y: 1}
    ],
    [
     {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -5), y: 5}, 
     {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -4), y: 8}, 
     {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -3), y: 2}, 
     {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -2), y: 1}, 
     {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -1), y: 6}, 
     {x: now, y: 1}
    ],
    [
     {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -5), y: 8}, 
     {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -4), y: 6}, 
     {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -3), y: 4}, 
     {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -2), y: 2}, 
     {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -1), y: 0}, 
     {x: now, y: 1}
    ],
    [
     {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -5), y: 1}, 
     {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -4), y: 0}, 
     {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -3), y: 2}, 
     {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -2), y: 3}, 
     {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -1), y: 2}, 
     {x: now, y: 1}
    ],
    [
     {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -5), y: 6}, 
     {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -4), y: 4}, 
     {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -3), y: 8}, 
     {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -2), y: 3}, 
     {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -1), y: 2}, 
     {x: now, y: 1}
    ],
    [
     {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -5), y: 1}, 
     {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -4), y: 3}, 
     {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -3), y: 6}, 
     {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -2), y: 9}, 
     {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -1), y: 5}, 
     {x: now, y: 1}
    ],
    [
     {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -5), y: 8}, 
     {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -4), y: 5}, 
     {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -3), y: 0}, 
     {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -2), y: 2}, 
     {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -1), y: 3}, 
     {x: now, y: 1}
    ],
    [
        {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -5), y: 2}, 
        {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -4), y: 4}, 
        {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -3), y: 1}, 
        {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -2), y: 2}, 
        {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -1), y: 3}, 
        {x: now, y: 1}
    ]
];

var color_hash = {  0 : ["A", "red"],
                    1 : ["B", "green"],
                    2 : ["C", "Yellow"],
                    3 : ["D", "orange"],
                    4 : ["F", "blue"],
                    5 : ["G", "pink"],
                    6 : ["H", "grey"],
                    7 : ["I", "purple"],
                    8 : ["J", "Coral"],
                    9 : ["K", "Crimson"],
                    10 : ["L", "DarkOliveGreen"],
                    11 : ["M", "DarkSeaGreen"],
                    12 : ["N", "DarkRed"],
                    13 : ["O", "DarkKhaki"],
                    14 : ["P", "Chocolate"],
                    15 : ["Q", "Black"]

                  }                      

// Define axis ranges & scales        
var yExtents = d3.extent(d3.merge(dataset), function (d) { return d.y; });
var xExtents = d3.extent(d3.merge(dataset), function (d) { return d.x; });

var xScale = d3.time.scale()
       .domain([xExtents[0], xExtents[1]])
       .range([padding, w - padding * 2]);

var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
       .domain([0, yExtents[1]])
       .range([h - padding, padding]);


// Create SVG element
var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);


// Define lines
var line = d3.svg.line()
       .x(function(d) { return x(d.x); })
       .y(function(d) { return y(d.y1, d.y2, d.y3); });

var pathContainers = svg.selectAll('g.line')
.data(dataset);

pathContainers.enter().append('g')
.attr('class', 'line')
.attr("style", function(d) {
    return "stroke: " + color_hash[dataset.indexOf(d)][1]; 
});

pathContainers.selectAll('path')
.data(function (d) { return [d]; }) // continues the data from the pathContainer
.enter().append('path')
  .attr('d', d3.svg.line()
    .x(function (d) { return xScale(d.x); })
    .y(function (d) { return yScale(d.y); })
  );

// add circles
pathContainers.selectAll('circle')
.data(function (d) { return d; })
.enter().append('circle')
.attr('cx', function (d) { return xScale(d.x); })
.attr('cy', function (d) { return yScale(d.y); })
.attr('r', 3); 

//Define X axis
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(xScale)
        .orient("bottom")
        .ticks(5);

//Define Y axis
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(yScale)
        .orient("left")
        .ticks(5);

//Add X axis
svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "axis")
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + (h - padding) + ")")
.call(xAxis);

//Add Y axis
svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "axis")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + padding + ",0)")
.call(yAxis);

// Add title      
svg.append("svg:text")
       .attr("class", "title")
   .attr("x", 20)
   .attr("y", 20)
   .text("Fruit Sold Per Hour");

/* var legend = d3.select("body").append("div")
   .attr("class", "legend")
   .attr('transform', 'translate(-20,50)'); */
// add legend   
 var legend = svg.append("g")
                  .attr("class", "legend1")
                  .attr('transform', 'translate(-20,50)')     


legend.selectAll('rect')
  .data(dataset)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", w - 75)
  .attr("y", function(d, i){ return i *  20;})
  .attr("width", 5)
  .attr("height", 5)
  .style("fill", function(d) { 
    var color = color_hash[dataset.indexOf(d)][1];
    return color;
  })

legend.selectAll('text')
  .data(dataset)
  .enter()
  .append("text")
  .attr("x", w - 65)
  .attr("width", 5)
  .attr("height", 5)
  .attr("y", function(d, i){ return i *  20 + 5;})
  .text(function(d) {
    var text = color_hash[dataset.indexOf(d)][0];
    return text;
  });


    </script>
</body>
```

How to place legends in div with specified hieght and width with scroll when the number of series increases

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "scroll when the number of series increases", please be more specific. You mean make it so that if you have more series than the page height can hold it becomes scrollable?

Comment: When i reduce chart height from 500 to 200 i can see only 7 legends on the right side of the chart. thats the reason i want to add the legend part in a div so that it get auto scroll even of the chart height is less

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can solve this by putting the chart and legend into two separate `<div>`'s.

First we will add them:

```
<body>
    <div id="chart" class="chart"></div>
    <div id="legend" class="legend"></div>
</body>
```

Second, we will set their styles (I did it here manually but you can use `setAttribute(...)` in your script).

```
.legend {
      overflow: auto;
      height: 200px;  
      width: 50px;  
        }

.chart {
     float: left;
       }
```

Setting `overflow: auto` is what makes the div scrollable. `float: left` makes the `<div>`'s display side-by-side.

Last, we will change the d3 script to reflect this by creating svg elements for each div.

```
var svg = d3.select("#chart")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);

var svg2 = d3.select("#legend")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 30)
    .attr("height", 20*dataset.length);
```

You can see the result [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bV5GE/).

Comment: Hi Mosho, solution which u gave works fine for sample example but when i apply samething in my project it doesnt display the legend color and values

Comment: but i can see the values when i check on the firebug console

Comment: I can only assume that it's not wide enough. If you make a fiddle I can help better.

Comment: @Mosho do you have any example to create scroll horizontally for plot ? for an example, if there are 100 x-axis label...I do not want to have a large plot. May be 50 labels and scroll scroll bar to move horizontally to view the rest of the labels.